# Is a type safe Class<? extends Entity> array possible?

Tags: java, arrays, generics

Is it possible to make the following code type safe?

```
Class<? extends Entity>[] test = (Class<? extends Entity>[]) new Class<?>[1];
```

EDIT: I need it for the input of the following function:

```
public <T extends Entity> T createEntity(final Class<T> clazz, final int id)
```

I can't use ArrayList, because of its bad garbage performance. I just wanted to get rid of the IDE warning, without suppressing it.

Comment: what are you trying to acomplish here ?

Comment: It is already as typesafe as it will ever be.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can only pick two of arrays and generics and type safety.  But if you use e.g. `ArrayList` instead of arrays you'll be fine.

Comment: Any other thing, instead of ArrayList?

Comment: Any `Collection` type, or anything defined with generics instead of arrays.